# Multiple Dictionary JSON file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, dictionary, error-handling, append

I have an online data of the following form:

```
{"headers": {"ai5": "3356", "debug": null, "random": null, "sd": "7.6"}, "post": {"event": "ggstart", "ts": "1462"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.033775", "game_id": "55107008"}}

{"headers": {"ai5": "8fa6", "debug": null, "random": null, "sd": "7.6"}, "post": {"event": "ggstart", "ts": "1475"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906", "game_id": "55107008"}}
```

I am expecting that I will have to read it considering each row as JSON format and keep on adding them to final data:

```
data = []
with open('new.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

But I am receiving error :

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Can some one please help me in understanding  what important point I am missing here.

Comment: Is it actually json in that line?
What is the output of `print(line)` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the middle line in your file. It's not a valid json (A blank line in fact), hence you are facing the Error.

Fix:

Add a `try/except` block.

```
import json
data = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            data.append(json.loads(line.strip()))
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{
'post': {
    'event': 'ggstart',
    'ts': '1462'
},
'bottle': {
    'timestamp': '2016-05-09 02:00:00.033775',
    'game_id': '55107008'
},
'headers': {
    'debug': None,
    'sd': '7.6',
    'random': None,
    'ai5': '3356'
},
'params': {}
}, 
{
    'post': {
        'event': 'ggstart',
        'ts': '1475'
    },
    'bottle': {
        'timestamp': '2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906',
        'game_id': '55107008'
    },
    'headers': {
        'debug': None,
        'sd': '7.6',
        'random': None,
        'ai5': '8fa6'
    },
    'params': {}
}]
```